# Django : How do I call "reverse" on a link to a static image file?

Tags: django, django-templates

In Django, I have images stored in site_media like this :

```
/site_media/somepath/image.jpg
```

The urls.py file has been set up to server these using :

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'staticfiles.views.serve')
)
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'staticfiles.views.serve')
)
```

So how can I make a reverse() or {% url %} call to one of these images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably easier to just use:

```
{{ MEDIA_URL }}somepath/image.jpg
```

assuming you've set up the [`MEDIA_URL`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-url) setting in your `settings.py`.

Also, you really don't want to serve static files through Django in a production environment. From the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#the-big-fat-disclaimer):

> Using this method is inefficient and insecure. Do not use this
>   in a production setting. Use this only for development.

One more thing - what is `staticfiles.views.serve`? Django has a [built in system](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) for serving static files, though the disclaimer above still applies.

You probably want to serve static files straight from Apache/nginx/whatever. It'll be heaps quicker.